# android : update my application on google store

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-update-app

I have question about update version of my application on **google play store**.

If I upload a new version `APK` application on **google play store**

- Current user can receive about update , download and install new version or not?
- If current user cannot receive that how to resolve it?

Comment: Automatic update will be there by Playstore app to user

Comment: Obviously user would get update in google play store app.

Answer (score 0):

The user will be getting the update if the versionCode and versionName has been changed

Comment: versionCode and versionName on AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to control the app in splash screen by implementing the check which version is on play store.

I mean to say forcefully ask the user to update the app.

Better to make web api and send data to server from splash screen which version is live on store.If it return true , enter app else ask him to update